# C++ compile error when using thread with vector::push_back as first param

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    thread s(&vector<int>::push_back,&a,3);
}
```

I get compile error for these code:

```
main.cpp:52:39: error: no matching function for call to
‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int>*, int)’

thread s(&vector<int>::push_back,&a,3);
```

can I get any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that it doesn't know which overload of `vector<int>::push_back` to use,

```
void vector<int>::push_back(const int& val);
```

or

```
void vector<int>::push_back(int&& val);
```

since they both have the same name.

The solution is to `static_cast` to the required function type, or declare a variable of the correct type,

e.g.

```
thread s(static_cast<void(vector<int>::*)(const int&)>(&vector<int>::push_back),&a,3);
```

or

```
void (vector<int>::* func)(const int&) = &vector<int>::push_back;
thread s(func, &a, 3);
```

I know, it's horribly ugly.

Comment: is there always an error for not static type method accessed as first param?

Comment: No, non-static member functions usually work just as you have used them. The issue is that there are two vector<int>::push_back functions, and it doesn't know which to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing a lambda:

```
thread s([](vector<int>& a, int b) {
     a.push_back(b);
}, std::ref(a), 3);
```